# Virtualenv failing with "does not start with prefix"

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have just downloaded python 3.6.1 from github and built it in a local dir. Now I am trying to make a virtualenv with that version of python but I keep getting:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/giorgio/tools/cpython-3.6.1/python
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2462, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 762, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 998, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1219, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1147, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1111, in change_prefix
    assert False, "Filename {} does not start with any of these prefixes: {}".format(filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename /home/giorgio/tools/cpython-3.6.1/Lib/os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['/usr/local', '/usr/local']
```

I don't want to install this version of python globally on the system. Is there another way to make virtualenv work with it?

Comment: Did you actually install it, or just run `./configure` and `make` in your tools directory?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I didn't want to actually install it system-wide, so i just run the `./configure` and `make`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think Python 3.6 introduced a new way of creating virtual environments that don't depend on routing through usr/local.

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error attempting to use my brew-installed version of Python 3.9.5  to create a new virtual environment on macOS.  (`mkvirtualenv` with `virtualenvwrapper`)

My command format is typically:

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 [env-name]
```

Not sure what caused this to get messed up, but ultimately I got it working again by running:

```
python3.9 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/myenvname
```

This puts the env in your normal spot, and you can still run `workon myenvname`

Answer (score 2):

The right way to achieve this is to set the prefix when you configure the build options to be a local directory and then perform `make install`. So if the directory you want to install things at is `$HOME/pythons` then in the build directory run:

```
./configure --prefix="${HOME}/pythons"
make
make install
```